# I want to make Voronoi type Cells go from 0-1 in UV space: so I can run a gradient through each cell individually. i.e. each cell runs from 0-1

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, shader-nodes, texture-coordinates

**Main issue:**
I have a cell like mask that I made on this texture. I want a gradient to run through each cell individually. I'm not sure if I can make cells into attributes or something and pass that way- not sure how to solve this. Picture of my texture and the reference I'm trying to copy are posted.

**Current Texture explanation**:
The texture has something similar to voronoi type texture. Take 1-0 UV space. Multiple by 10 on x and y. Giving 10 by 10 grid. Mod these results so there is a zero on each result. Then use distance function paired with color ramp to make circles. (img1)

Last there is a noise texture to make circles all wavy. (img2)

**My dumb boy attempts**:
So what I tried is this formula. Dot Product the "wavy texture" against it's self to make to cells go from 0-1.Multiply by a number and run this through fraction function thing-this makes cell repeat it's self inside of it's self. This is the best I could do(img3)... But it doesn't really look like the reference image. (Last img) Please Help. This is for my wife's company and I really want to help her make 3D marketing. I can also post the blend file.

[image]
[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly you expect. It is hard to recreate the exact same result with some chaotic distorted noise when you do not know all the parameters that were used for the reference. All in all I think you were quite close with the second setup, just missing a bit more rainbowy colors and then playing around with the values to get it more similar:

[image: rainbow noise]

As I said, not easy to get it exactly the same, but I think this is going in the right direction. It is all a matter of tweaking the values and colors until you are satisfied with the result. Here is mine in the same context as your reference:

[image: rainbow mushroom]